# extra "]" displayed when using htlatex in TL 2013 with \usepackage{hyperref}

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

I noticed I am getting a new char displayed on the HTML page which did not exist when I was using TL 2012 with htlatex.  I narrowed it down to including `\usepackage{hyperref}` This extra "]" shows only in the HTML, not in the PDF

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\begin{document}
text
\section{example using Table[Plot...]}
text
\end{document}
```

gives expected output

[image]

Now adding `\usepackage{hyperref}`  gives this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
text
\section{example using Table[Plot...]}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the extra "]" there.

Command used and part of the display on the screen:

```
>htlatex foo5.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty

Package auxhook Warning: Cannot patch \document,
(auxhook)                using \AtBeginDocument instead.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)

Package hyperref Message: Stopped early.

)

Package hyperref Message: Driver: htex4ht.

[1 file foo5.html
 file foo5.css
 file foo5.tmp
]
Execute script `foo5.lg'
----------------------------
t4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:28 kpathsea)
t4ht -f/foo5.tex 
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env)
Entering foo5.lg
Entering foo5.css
Entering foo5.tmp
>
```

The HTML generated is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)"> 
<!-- html --> 
<meta name="src" content="foo5.tex"> 
<meta name="date" content="2013-06-22 21:56:00"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo5.css"> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 4--><p class="noindent" >text
   <span 
class="cmbx-12x-x-144">]</span>
   <h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-10001"></a>example using Table[Plot...]</h3>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >text  
</body></html>
```

New installation of TL2013, on Linux mint 15

```
>which htlatex
/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/i386-linux/htlatex

>latex -v
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.5.16; using libpng 1.5.16
Compiled with zlib 1.2.7; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.03
>

>tex4ht
----------------------------
tex4ht.c (2012-07-25-19:36 kpathsea)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bug in `nameref.4ht`, the support file of `tex4ht` for package `nameref`:

```
\def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
    \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[#7]{#8}}
\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[#7]{#8}}
\HLet\NR@sect\:tempc
```

Argument `#7` contains the title string with `example using Table[Plot...]`, calling it as optional argument becomes:

```
\...{<#1>}...{<#6>}[example using Table[Plot...]]{<#8>}
```

That means, already the *first* closing bracket `]` matches and closes the optional argument. The second `]` becomes the next argument instead of `{<#8>}`.

**Patch:**

The trick is to use curly braces: `[{#7}]` instead of `[#7]`. Then this is robust, if `#7` contains square brackets:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11 %
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{%
    \def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
        \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
        \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}%
    }
    \def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
       \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
       \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
       \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
    \HLet\NR@sect\:tempc
  }{}%
}%
\@makeother\:
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text
\section{example using Table[Plot...]}
text
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

Thanks to the [bug report #185](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?185) of michael.h21 (see [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120617/extra-displayed-when-using-htlatex-in-tl-2013-with-usepackagehyperref#comment269014_120620)), CV Radhakrishnan has updated [`nameref.ht4`](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/download.php?file_id=140) in the source repository with date 2013-06-28. This update fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks. But now pdflatex does not compile.
`! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...5}{##6}[{##7}]{##8}} \HLet 
                                                  \NR@sect \:tempc \ifx \hyp...
l.4 \begin{document}`  What should I do? thanks.
                    
?

Comment: I've added logic around your patch, so that it is only seen when htlatex is running, using `\if\texforht ... patch .... \fi`, now document works with both pdflatex and with htlatex no problem. thanks.

Comment: @Nasser: Thanks, I have added a test for package `tex4ht` in the patch. Otherwise `\HLet` would be undefined without `tex4ht`.

Comment: I posted this issue with patch based on your code to tex4ht bug repository - https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?185