# using \label causes error with htlatex when hyperref is used in TL 2013

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

in TL 2013, new installation.  When adding `\label` below causes an error in htlatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  \label{eq1}
   x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

compiling

```
htlatex note_on_lecture_2_21_2013.tex

(./note_on_lecture_2_21_2013.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\a:newlabel ...utoref\string \endcsname {\NR:Type 
                                                  }#1}
l.4 \begin{equation}  \label{eq1}

?
```

Removing `hyperref` causes the error to go away. Also keeping hyperref but removing `\label` the error goes away.

Adding the patch posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120617/extra-displayed-when-using-htlatex-in-tl-2013-with-usepackagehyperref) does not help:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\:=11 %
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{%
    \def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
        \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
        \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}%
    }
    \def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
       \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
       \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
       \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
    \HLet\NR@sect\:tempc
  }{}%
}%
\@makeother\:
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  \label{eq1}
x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the same way, gives the same error.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht))
(./note_on_lecture_2_21_2013.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\a:newlabel ...utoref\string \endcsname {\NR:Type 
                                                  }#1}
l.23 \begin{equation}  \label{eq1}

?
```

Using

```
>latex -v
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
```

On Linux mint 15.

Comment: If I add `\section*{}` before the equation, no error appears. By the way, the same happens with TL 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug that should be reported to the tex4ht list but this works around this case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\expandafter\let\csname NR:Type\endcsname\relax
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  \label{eq1}
   x=y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I posted a bug report - https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?186